# How to create a time triggered Notification that works on all Android Devices

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin

I'm trying to make a notification that get triggered after a certain amount of time has passed. In an attempt to achieve this I have this AlarmReceiver class that inherits from BroadCast receiver and works on devices running up to about API 23. It doesn't work on my emulator currently running API 27. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
companion object {
    val PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "dj"
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationIntent = Intent(context, NotificationActivity::class.java)

    val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity::class.java)
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent)

    val pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT){
        //I create the notification channel on the next line, but it doesn't seem to work
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL,
                "DailyJokes", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
        notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        val notification = Notification.Builder(context, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setChannelId("dj")
                .setContentText("KDW")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle("CCC")
                .build()
        notificationManager.notify(1,notification)    

    } else {
        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "dj")
    val sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + "raw/drumroll")
    builder = builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setTicker("TICKER Text")
            .setContentText("KDW setContentText")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setChannelId("dj")
            .setSound(sound)

    notificationManager.notify(1, builder!!.build())
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the code that triggers the notification, anything off here?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification)



 val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    val notificationIntent = Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION")


    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")

    val broadcast = getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5)
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, broadcast)

}
}
```

I also have a receiver in my Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Even with all this the bug still lurks. I'm new to Kotlin, today makes a week since I started. My swift experience prepared me well but I just can't seem to get a hold on notifications :/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code , you need to register the receiver in either the Manifest or a context.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Comment: Thanks @thomas stevens,  I revised my question and included the receiver code snippet from my Manifest. This notification thing has been my toughest challenge in working with Android, I appreciate your help!

Comment: I have run your code up in android studio. The notification works when run directly from the activity, and works as is on api < 23 so I can only assume there is something wrong with the alarm manager broadcast/receive on api >= 23. I will take a look again in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

is your channel even created ? 
your comparison is in the wrong direction ->

`android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` it should be `>=` instead

and only the channel creation needs to be guarded against O, not the notification creation.

Comment: I believe I created the notification in the first line of my if conditional. When I try to change the direction I get a bunch of red underlines saying : "Call requires API level 26 (current min is 15): android.app.Notification.Builder#setChannelId more... " and still no notification triggered on API 27 – notifications are tough stuff huh

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, I am not used to your yoda style comparison, it true me off

Comment: The non-channel code still does not need to be in that code and repeated
but whatever.  The easiest way for you to debug this is to add logs to know at which step you are doing it wrong (is the broadcast sent, is it received, etc)

Comment: My code didn't start out like that. I've just been moving alot of code around to try to solve this issue. And the truth is this "is" working code, only problem is it doesn't work on all the android devices. So I'm confident that the broadcast is being sent and received otherwise the notifications would not have come through on my Tab 4 running API 19. I think the problem is with my notification channel... as this is the only new requirement for constructing notifications. Also, I'm new to android development -- about week of experience under my belt, I don't know how to add logs.